# Android 4.4: ToggleButton background is visible even the view is "GONE"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-selector, android-togglebutton

It seems that my problem is specific for Android versions 4.4 and above. Here is what I am trying to do:

I have an ExpandableListView with GroupViews and ChapterViews.
GroupViews contain a toggle button which is visible only if they have children views otherwise set to View.GONE (which is also default)

```
 ToggleButton toggleExpansion = (ToggleButton) chapter.findViewById(R.id.toggleExpansion);
        if(getChildrenCount(groupPosition) == 0){ // Not an expandable group
            text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.title_textcolor_empty));
            toggleExpansion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{  // An expandable group

            toggleExpansion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if(isExpanded){
                toggleExpansion.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                toggleExpansion.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
```

The background of these buttons are defined by a selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/maximized_group_item" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/minimized_group_item" />
</selector>
```

And here is the layout definition of the GroupView which is inflated above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleExpansion"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_expander"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textOff=" "
        android:textOn=" "
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textChapterTitle"
        style="@style/list_text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the code it works fine and as expected in Android 4.1.2 but in 4.4 (both on emulator and device) the image minimized_group_item shows up, even though the ToggleButton is "GONE".

So I think it has something to do with the Android version. Before I updated my device from 2.3.3 to CM11 (4.4), this code worked fine.

I could not find anything related on web. I also have prepared screenshots but can't post them (reputation < 10) but I have uploaded them [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk2kG.png).
I hope you find this weird behaviour interesting and I am wondering, how to solve this problem.

Comment: Differences in layout in conjunction with Android versions can occur with Styles and Themes. Have you tried commenting out that TextViews style? Also, could it be that you think a view is gone, but actually it is invisible because of its color? Like black text on top of a black background?

Comment: TextViews style is only attributes such as the width, height, margin etc. The grey background shows, where the TextView is located. I have tried with emulators and a device. I don't think theme should be any problem. The view is gone and I know that because the view does not take up any place on the layout. I have also tried with INVISIBLE. Anyway, even if the View is visible, there is somehow that second (wrong) icon appearing.

Comment: That second icon on top of the first one could result from overdrawing. Try invalidating the ListView using `notifyDataSetChanged`on its Adapter to force a complete redraw.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have posted a solution below. This was pure my mistake. But it is useful to put there, that setGroupIndicator behaves differently in different versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

This project was old and I didn't do anything for months. Apparently I set in the code `expandableLectures.setGroupIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_expander));`

Selector as group indicator does not work. It doesn't even show up below Android 4.4. Therefore I thought this is due to the Android version but it was only because I set it as GroupIndicator.